# What is the deployment controller sync period for kube-controller-manager?

Tags: kubernetes, kube-controller-manager

kube-controller-manager has the following property

```
-deployment-controller-sync-period duration     Default: 30s
Period for syncing the deployments.
```

What does this actually control and what does `period for syncing the deployments` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haha most curious thing. You'd expect it does something like controlling how often the controller checks whether the status of Deployment objects are compatible with spec or if there is a change needed.

However currently the controller-manager is notified on changes by the apiserver so it always inherently knows this information already.

There is [Issue #71510](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71510) where someone points out that parameter seems to be unused. I've done my own [search for the parameter](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=deployment-controller-sync-period&type=) and a related [search for the variable](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DeploymentControllerSyncPeriod&type=). As far as I can tell all of these uses are for copying this value around, conversions, declarations, etc, and none of them actually use it for anything at all.

A good test would be setting it to a year and see what happens. I haven't done that though.

Comment: I did see that defect but noted there was no response. My question was seeing a 30 second pause in the controller manager logs after a leader election and I was interested to see if a particular parameter controls this pause.

Comment: so, how does apiserver knows about the change? does kubelet calls apiserver?