# What is the interval of kube-controller-manager control loop?

Tags: loops, kubernetes, kubelet, kube-controller-manager, reconcile

I see this in Kubernetes doc,

> In Kubernetes, controllers are control loops that watch the state of
> your cluster, then make or request changes where needed. Each
> controller tries to move the current cluster state closer to the
> desired state.

Also this,

> The Deployment controller and Job controller are examples of
> controllers that come as part of Kubernetes itself ("built-in"
> controllers).

But, I couldn't find how does the control loop work. Does it check the current state of the cluster every few seconds? If yes, what is the default value?

I also found something interesting here,

[What is the deployment controller sync period for kube-controller-manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55453072/what-is-the-deployment-controller-sync-period-for-kube-controller-manager)

Answer (score 3):

I would like to start explaining that the [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-controller-manager) is a collection of individual control processes tied together to reduce complexity.

Being said that, the control process responsible for monitoring the node's health and a few other parameters is the [Node Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#node-controller), and it does that by reading the [Heartbeats](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#heartbeats) sent by the [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) agent in the nodes.

According to the Kubernete's documentation:

> For nodes there are two forms of heartbeats:
>
> - updates to the `.status` of a Node
> - [Lease](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/cluster-resources/lease-v1/) objects within the `kube-node-lease` namespace. Each Node has an    associated Lease object.
>
> Compared to updates to `.status` of a Node, a Lease is a lightweight
> resource. Using Leases for heartbeats reduces the performance impact
> of these updates for large clusters.
>
> The kubelet is responsible for creating and updating the `.status` of
> Nodes, and for updating their related Leases.
>
> - The kubelet updates the node's `.status` either when there is change in    status or if there has been no update for a configured interval.
>   The    default interval for `.status` updates to Nodes is 5 minutes,
>   which is    much longer than the 40 second default timeout for
>   unreachable nodes.
> - The kubelet creates and then updates its Lease object every 10    seconds (the default update interval). Lease updates occur independently from updates to the Node's `.status`. If the Lease update
>   fails, the kubelet retries, using exponential backoff that starts at 200 milliseconds and capped at 7 seconds.

As for the [Kubernetes Objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/) running in the nodes:

> Kubernetes objects are persistent entities in the Kubernetes system.
> Kubernetes uses these entities to represent the state of your cluster.
> Specifically, they can describe:
>
> - What containerized applications are running (and on which nodes)
> - The resources available to those applications
> - The policies around how those applications behave, such as restart policies, upgrades, and fault-tolerance
>
> A Kubernetes object is a "record of intent"--once you create the
> object, the Kubernetes system will constantly work to ensure that
> object exists. By creating an object, you're effectively telling the
> Kubernetes system what you want your cluster's workload to look like;
> this is your cluster's desired state.

Depending on the Kubernetes Object, the controller mechanism is responsible for maintaining its desired state. The [Deployment Object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for example, uses the [Replica Set](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) underneath to maintain the desired described state of the Pods; while the [Statefulset Object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) uses its own Controller for the same purpose.

To see a complete list of Kubernetes Objects managed by your cluster, you can run the command: `kubectl api-resources`

Comment: thanks for this, this clarifies for nodes, what about the resources in the nodes, like deployments or statefulsets?

Comment: @karthikeayan Just edited the answer including that info.